# Why does my app open more iterations

Tags: android

When I open my app for the first time, it launches the splash screen, then goes to a home page.

Usually when I reopen the app (by pressing the app icon) I am directed to the home page properly. However, sometimes I get the splash screen again.

This wouldn't be a problem (because it means I'm reopening the app) but when I press the back button from the home page, I see the last iteration of my app (still open and running).

So what is going on?

Thank you

Comment: Have you written to finish the activity when the onPause event occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `launchMode="singleInstance"` to your android `<activity>` manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Generally the default behavior of android apps makes sense. If you have multiple activities you generally expect that pressing the back button will move you back to the previous state. It is possible to have multiple versions of the same activity in your activity stack and negating this would not be expected. If I filled out a form twice then pressed back to the first form I wouldn't expect it to contain my second form's data, for instance. But for specific types of applications this does not make sense. There are multiple ways to handle this so you need to be aware of what you app will be doing and what the expectations for your app will be.

Comment: my app "finishes" the splash page before going to the home page. If I pressed the back button on my home page then the app should close (since all activities are finished). If I placed launchMode single instance, wouldn't the splash page still show up since it isnt there? Should I only use the singleInstance on the home page? Thanks

Comment: How are you "going to the home page" and in general making the transitions between activities?